# Same word three times over

Tags: wordplay

Distinguish:

"Multiply."

"Multiply."

"Multiply."

(Not sure why this didn't post without extra words.  It's the same word over and again.)

Comment: you're a madman.

Comment: Truly, @parz , this triplet is to blame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what the question is here, but I can think of

> three different parsings of "multiply", and I suppose that might be what's sought. 1, the adverb, as in "I was doubly impressed; he, multiply". 2, the verb, as in "I wished to exponentiate; he, to multiply". 3, the adjective, as in "I use two-ply tissue; he, multiply".

Comment: Sorry i wasn't around at the moment you figured this.  Fun solution!